# How to set ASP.Net MVC webgrid pagination images for First,Last

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I'm trying to set pagination navigation images instead of text but getting design time error. Please have a look at my code and give me suggestions on how to achieve it.

```
<div id="gridContent" style=" padding:20px; ">
    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    firstText: '<img src="@Url.Content('~/Content/Images/logo3.png')" />',
    previousText: "<",
    nextText: ">",
    lastText: ">>", 
    numericLinksCount: 5,       
    columns:
        grid.Columns
        (
        grid.Column(columnName: "ID", header: "ID", format: @<text>@item.ID</text>,style:"SmallCols"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "FirstName", header: "First Name", format: @<text>@item.FirstName</text>,style:"NameColWidth" ),
        grid.Column(columnName: "LastName", header: "Last Name", format: @<text>@item.LastName</text>,style:"NameColWidth"),

        grid.Column(columnName: "StateName", header: "State Name", format: @<text>@item.StateName</text>,style:"NameColWidth"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "CityName", header: "City Name", format: @<text>@item.CityName</text>,style:"NameColWidth"),
        grid.Column(header: "IsActive",
        format: @<text><input id="select" class="box" name="select" type="checkbox" @(item.IsActive ? "checked='checked'" : "") value="@item.IsActive" /></text>
                          , style: "text-center checkbox-width SmallCols")

                 ))

</div>
```

**Specially see this code**

`firstText: '<img src="@Url.Content('~/Content/Images/logo3.png')" />',`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808483/use-images-instead-of-text-in-webgrid-asp-mvc

Answer (score 1):

i have done this job by jquery.

```
function SetPagerNavImage()
{
    $(".webgrid-footer a").each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().trim();
        if (text == "<<") {
            $(this).html('<img src="/images/first.png"/>');
        }

        if (text == ">>") {
            $(this).html('<img src="/images/last.png"/>');
        }

        if (text == "<") {
            $(this).html('<img src="/images/back.png"/>');
        }

        if (text == ">") {
            $(this).html('<img src="/images/next.png"/>');
        }

    });

}
```

### full code

```
@model  WebGridSample.Models.StudentVm
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Show";
}



<style type="text/css">

    .webgrid-table {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border: solid 1px #98BF21;
        background-color: white;
    }

        .webgrid-table td, th {
            border: 1px solid #98BF21;
            padding: 3px 7px 2px;
        }

    .webgrid-header {
        background-color: #A7C942;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .webgrid-header a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

    .webgrid-footer {
    }

        .webgrid-footer a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

    .webgrid-row-style {
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    }

    .webgrid-alternating-row {
        background-color: #EAF2D3;
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    }

    .SmallCols {
        width: 10%;
    }

    .NameColWidth {
        width: 20%;
    }

</style>

<h2>Sample WebGrid Demo</h2>

@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(null, rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize, canPage: true, defaultSort: Model.sort); //, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent"
    grid.Bind(Model.Students, autoSortAndPage: false, rowCount: Model.RowCount);
    //grid.PageIndex = Model.CurrentPage;
}

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Show", "WebGrid", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmDetails" }))
{
    <div id="gridContent" style=" padding:20px; ">
        @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        firstText: "<<",
        previousText: "<",
        nextText: ">",
        lastText: ">>", 
        numericLinksCount: 5,       
        columns:
            grid.Columns
            (
            grid.Column(columnName: "ID", header: "ID", format: @<text>@item.ID</text>,style:"SmallCols"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "FirstName", header: "First Name", format: @<text>@item.FirstName</text>,style:"NameColWidth" ),
            grid.Column(columnName: "LastName", header: "Last Name", format: @<text>@item.LastName</text>,style:"NameColWidth"),

            grid.Column(columnName: "StateName", header: "State Name", format: @<text>@item.StateName</text>,style:"NameColWidth"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "CityName", header: "City Name", format: @<text>@item.CityName</text>,style:"NameColWidth"),
            grid.Column(header: "IsActive",
            format: @<text><input id="select" class="box" name="select" type="checkbox" @(item.IsActive ? "checked='checked'" : "") value="@item.IsActive" /></text>
                              , style: "text-center checkbox-width SmallCols")

                     ))

        @Html.Hidden("dir", grid.SortDirection)
        @Html.Hidden("col", grid.SortColumn)
        @Html.Hidden("page", Model.CurrentPage)
    </div>

}



@section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SetSortArrows();
        SetPagerNavImage();
    });

    function SetPagerNavImage()
    {
        $(".webgrid-footer a").each(function () {
            var text = $(this).text().trim();
            if (text == "<<") {
                $(this).html('<img src="/images/first.png"/>');
            }

            if (text == ">>") {
                $(this).html('<img src="/images/last.png"/>');
            }

            if (text == "<") {
                $(this).html('<img src="/images/back.png"/>');
            }

            if (text == ">") {
                $(this).html('<img src="/images/next.png"/>');
            }

        });

    }

    function SetSortArrows() {
        var dir = $('#dir').val();
        var col = $('#col').val();
        var header = $('th a[href*=' + col + ']');
        if (dir == 'Ascending') {
            header.text(header.text() + ' ▲');
        }
        if (dir == 'Descending') {
            header.text(header.text() + ' ▼');
        }
    };


    </script>
}
```